# MySQL: INTO OUTFILE in csv generates invalid csv format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to export sql query result to csv file it works but the out csv data does not look good and strange.

MySQL Table Download Link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtr215bcxqo3wsy/data.sql?dl=0

CSV Generated by sql query:

Download Link to original Generated CSV File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnjf7ycmh08hd22/data.csv?dl=0

I am using following code:

```
$query = <<<EOL
 SELECT * FROM data  ORDER BY  FN ASC limit 3 
 INTO OUTFILE 'folder/data.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
EOL;

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Why csv format is looking so weird and unacceptable? 
If I try same code for some other table then everything works like charm then what's wrong?

Comment: your fields have line breaks in them. and since you've specified that lines are terminated by `\n`, any `\n` inside your fields terminate that "row".

Comment: Could you provide the actual text file that is created and not just how it looks when imported into a spreadsheet?

Comment: @Terry Just added generated file. please check

Comment: @MarcB that makes sense. But can you please guide me that how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: try `fields escaped by '\\'`, see if that escapes the literal `\n` into `\\n`. otherwise you'll probably need str_replace and convert the linebreaks into something else (maybe html `<br>`?)

Comment: I can't use str_replace as i have more than 10 million rows. that is why I am using this approach to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See final answer below**

It looks like your lines are terminated by `\\n` and it is throwing the extra slashes in random places.

Instead try a double slash followed by an n (`\\n`) and see what happens:

```
$query = <<<EOL
 SELECT * FROM data  ORDER BY  FN ASC limit 3 
 INTO OUTFILE 'folder/data.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
EOL;

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

**EDIT**

**Final Answer**

Another observation: I noticed that in your PROP_TYPE field, there are \r\n characters. Is there any way you can filter them out in your query using the `REPLACE()` function?

I know you are looking for a solution that is SQL based, and this is a hard issue because of the massive amount of data. Hope this leads you to the correct solution.

As you mentioned, using `update data set PROP_TYPE = replace(PROP_TYPE, '"','')` fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but still did not work

Comment: Does the file look any different? It is difficult to test for sure without data from the actual database (which is not really possible for us).

Comment: Please download database (3 rows) https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtr215bcxqo3wsy/data.sql?dl=0

Comment: Thanks @Terry for your efforts. I just posted answer myself to this question below so please have a look :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider simply using PHP to connect to MySQL, run query, then output to csv.

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="user";
$password="password";
$database="dbName";

# open connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY FN ASC limit 3;";
$STH = $dbh->query($sql);    

$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    # write to csv file
    $fs = fopen("folder/data.csv","a");
        fputcsv($fs, $row);
    fclose($fs);    
}

# close connection
$dbh = null;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for great response.
This is good but not perfect for 10 million rows. this would be very slow.

Comment: Yet your query limits to 3? Also, why would you need to export this many rows to a flatfile? If exporting to another system why not connect to ODBC?

Comment: Well 3 is just for example and quick testing. And I need to import in flatfile because it is my client's requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed my issue.

Actually @Terry is right. There was some issue with a field PROP_TYPE in table. 
PROP_TYPE field had double quotes " in its values that was causing issue.
For example

PROP_TYPE

"Value 1"

"Value 2" ....

So first of all I had to remove extra double quotes using `update data set PROP_TYPE = replace(PROP_TYPE, '"','')` so now my issue is fixed.

Thanks all of you for your efforts.

I really appreciate.

Comment: Thanks for posting. If you would not mind, could you "accept" my updated answer by checking the checkmark beside it? This will give us both "points" on Stackoverflow and is a good way to show appreciation for the work put into answering a question. Glad you got a solution that worked!